# Using Ocamllex for lexing strings (The Tiger Compiler)

Tags: ocaml, lex, tiger, ocamllex

I'm trying to follow Appel's "Modern Compiler Implementation in ML" and am writing the lexer using Ocamllex.

The specification asks for the lexer to return strings *after* translating escape sequences.
The following code is an excerpt from the ocamllex input file:

```
 rule tiger = parse
 ...
 | '"'
     { let buffer = Buffer.create 1 in
       STRING (stringl buffer lexbuf)
     }
 and  stringl buffer = parse
 | '"' { Buffer.contents buffer }
 | "\\t" { Buffer.add_char buffer '\t'; stringl buffer lexbuf }
 | "\\n" { Buffer.add_char buffer '\n'; stringl buffer lexbuf }
 | "\\n" { Buffer.add_char buffer '\n'; stringl buffer lexbuf }
 | '\\' '"' { Buffer.add_char buffer '"'; stringl buffer lexbuf }
 | '\\' '\\' { Buffer.add_char buffer '\\'; stringl buffer lexbuf }
 | eof { raise End_of_file }
 | _ as char { Buffer.add_char buffer char; stringl buffer lexbuf }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in looking at how the [Ocaml lexer](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/ocaml/trunk/parsing/lexer.mll?rev=10250&view=auto) does this (search for `and string`). In essence, it's the same method as yours, without the nice local buffer (I find your code nicer on this point, but this is a bit less efficient), a bit more complex because more escaping is supported, and using an escape table (char_for_backslash) to factorize similar rules.

Also, you have the rule `"\\n"` repeated twice, and I think `1` is a very pessimistic estimate of your string length, I would rather use `20` here (to avoid needless resizing).

Comment: Thanks! A goldmine of examples. I never thought the Ocaml compiler code would be so clear.

Comment: @nimrodm you should also keep in mind that some of the code there is quite old, so not everything reflects the current best practice of OCaml development.